# Memory leak in Django with Gunicorn and max-requests is already set

Tags: django, kubernetes, memory-leaks, gunicorn, prometheus

I have a Django application that is integrated with Gunicorn and Prometheus and Kubernetes. It's an application that queries ElasticSearch.

my Gunicorn config is:

```
exec gunicorn wsgi:application \
    --worker-class gthread \
    --bind 0.0.0.0:15236 \
    --workers 40 \
    --threads 4 \
    --log-level=info \
    --log-file=- \
    --timeout 20 \
    --reload
```

**My Problem**

Memory is gradually increasing.
And when I add `--max-requests 500` config for Gunicorn, my memory still increases and my Pod becomes Evicted!
I also deleted all the URLs except for `url('', include('django_prometheus.urls'))` to ensure that the memory leak is not caused by my code.
I also checked the Prometheus directory and It was only 1mb so it is not caused by Prometheus.
and DEBUG is set to False.

**Questions**

What is it possibly causing the memory leak?

And why is `max-requests` not helping at all and only worsening?

**Versions**

Django==3.1.1

gunicorn==20.0.4

django-prometheus==2.1.0

Comment: How do you check memory usage? How fast memory is eaten by django service?

Comment: I check it using htop and prometheus graphs. in development, it went from 144mb to 173mb in 4hours with max-requests set. in production, it went from 1.7Gb to 3.3Gb in 3 days without max-requests. @DmitryBelaventsev

Comment: @Ava did you figured out? I'm having the same problem with gunicorn + fastapi. Memory increase at rest.

Comment: @Kira Unfortunately, no